# jQuery prevent default but also keep custom events

Tags: jquery, events, preventdefault

I have a web page with a hook on all body click events:

```
if (0 == $('body').hasEventListener("click.custom").length) {
    $('body').bind("click.custom", function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    });
}
```

I want this method to output **all** clicked elements, but I am running into issues in places where I have additional event handlers. Consider the following code:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="my-link">Click</a>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".my-link", function(e) {
        alert("not allowed to click this");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

What ends up happening is the preventDefault call prevents my custom event from running.
I want the default event that would redirect the user to the link to be prevented, but I want any custom events to be fired.

Sure, it is possible to manually trigger every event from anywhere prevent default is called, but is there a generic way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: When is this custom event supposed to be triggered?

Comment: Your code as far as I can tell should work correctly; here is an duplication exactly as you have it above: http://jsfiddle.net/pXAhA/4/ Please modify your question with more info to assist potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your hasEventListener method implementation is, which I think is preventing the custom event binding,

But if you remove the check, it works fine.

http://jsbin.com/udonew/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Definitely my error - I had a custom preventDefault defined, and it contained:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Clearly that was the issue. Thank you!